# When marshalling a class from c# to native c++ does it clone?

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

If I have c# code like

```
[DllImport("SomeDll")]
private static extern void passAClass(ClassType myClass);
```

and call it like

```
ClassType myClass = new ClassType();
passAClass(myClass);
```

I can see that the class (its data segment) is passed to the dll as a pointer, but I am not certain if the runtime copies the class data from its location into new memory and then passes a pointer to that new memory, or if it passes a pointer to the memory location of the class directly.

I can see that if the dll changes data in the memory, it receives a pointer to, that changes is visible in c# after the call, but that could be because it does yet another copy of memory back into where the managed class is stored.

Comment: I *think* that when you are marshalling the instance that is just passing enough information to show how the object should interact and what its structure looks like - data + metadata + location of definition. Based on that, I believe that in addition to the structure of how to work with the data, the actual object passed is just a reference so that changes made remotely do change the object's data. Not 100%.

Comment: It is the point to the instance of the class.  Be careful because the class may contain pointers to the actual data.  For example an array in a class is a pointer and the size of the point may vary depending if the array is local or global.  The array should be made static so it can be accessed by the dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but that could be because it does yet another copy of memory back

No, that is not automatic, you explicitly have to give the argument the [Out] attribute to ensure that it copies back.  The fact that you do see the changes back without the attribute proves that the class is *blittable*.  In other words, the class' fields are all of a simple value type and they did not get re-arranged by the CLR.  So the managed layout is identical to the unmanaged layout, allowing the pinvoke marshaller to pin the object and pass a pointer.

It is not unusual.  Best not to make it an accident, you might lose a day of your life some rainy day when you port the native code to x64 for example.  Giving the class the [StructLayout] attribute to ensure sequential layout is a good idea.

Comment: I should have mentioned that in actual use I _do_ use structLayout sequential (though I think it is actual the default?)
I read your answer as confirming that a copy is not made for simple types, so if the passed class is a huge array it will only pin it and pass the pointer, as opposed to expensively copying the array two times?

What would be a case of a non blittable argument? A class c1 with a reference to another class c2, where only c1's data is then passed, containing a useless pointer to c2?